# bluetooth developer studio new project

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

Trying out the Bluetooth Developer Studio (BDS) tool and having some startup issue with not being able to create/ save a new project on a Windows 7 PC.

No matter what path or folder I choose the 'OK' button would not be enabled - screenshot attached.

[image: Screenshot. Ok option disabled.]

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a meaningful namespace name.  The gray text `com.CompanyName` is only a hint.  Once you provide a name for the namespace, OK button will become enabled.